# Permission Denied from Firebase using curl and javascript

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a Firebase with a security config like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "serviceproviders": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        },
        "bookings": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['phone', 'time', 'date', 'apikey'])",
            "apikey": {
                // only allow valid apikey
                ".validate": "root.child('serviceproviders/' + newData.val()).exists()"
            }
        },
        "status": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that users can only post `/bookings/` with a valid `apikey`, that is, an `apikey` that can be found in `/serviceproviders/`.

In the Firebase simulator, this works as expected. However, when I use `curl` from the terminal, or Javascript from a html page, I get `error: permission denied` back from Firebase. I send exactly the same data (copy & paste).

My `curl` command looks like this:

```
$ curl -X POST -d '{"phone":"004512345678", "date":"2014-07-31","time":"10:00","apikey":"AA227D80-122C-4E5D-AEDF-24A829FA6403"}'  https://example.firebaseIO.com/bookings/.json
```

And I get back:

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

Comment: Did you try the simulator tab in your dashboard? You haven't actually passed auth credentials but you are checking auth !== null. No write access is going to be allowed unless you pass a valid auth token in your curl commond.

Comment: @Kato - I have ".write": true, for the /bookings/ path, so no auth should be needed to post here.

Comment: If it works in the simulator, it will work in REST, assuming the payloads and auth creds exactly match. You can also try [debugging the request locally](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-query-parameters) by creating an auth token with debug: true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after many hours of pulling my hair, I realized that in the guide on Firebase.com, the `".validate"` rules are inside a block denoting the ID under that path, thus:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "serviceproviders": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        },
        "bookings": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": true,
            "$bookings_id": {
                "apikey": {
                    // only allow valid apikey
                    ".validate": "root.child('serviceproviders/' + newData.val()).exists()"
                },
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['apikey','date','time','phone'])"
            }
        },
        "status": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

works as expected, because of the `"$bookings_id"` block.

Comment: Can't help thinking that the simulator should have caught this.